# App metadata rejected because of Core NFC but it is not used anywhere in app code or pods code

Tags: ios

I submitted application to apple and they responded that "we need a video that demonstrates the use of the Core NFC"

> Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
>
> We're looking forward to completing our review of your app. Before we
> can continue, we need a video that demonstrates the use of the Core
> NFC feature in the current version in use on a physical iOS device.

and they want me to do video demonstrating NFC usage in the app, I don't see how to respond them by saying we don't use it at all. I searched whole code base for NFC and also pods that are included and I don't see any. And only thing I have in mind is that maybe some binary library I use "regula forensic document reader" can have hidden some NFC code inside but that is just my wild guess as they also don't mention NFC in their documentation.

they also say:

> Next Steps
>
> Create the demo video, add a link to the video in the App Review
> Information section of your app’s page in App Store Connect, and reply
> to this message in Resolution Center.

So I am lost a little here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just add review notes stating that the app doesn't use NFC, add the same response to the issue and resubmit and see what happens.

Comment: Any more feedback from Apple after your submission?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember in what project this was and how it was solved or if I solved it at all right now.. will try to get back here and respond if I get into that again...

Comment: I'm now getting this same issue.  We don't have NFC in this build, no references in code, no framework and no entitlement.  I pushed back to the reviewer and waiting for a response.

Comment: @DarrenEhlers I am running into the same issue. What was the response from Apple. Did you have to submit a recording in any case? Please let me know.

Comment: If you use Onfido this can cause the rejection

Comment: Here's a thread with Info: https://github.com/onfido/onfido-ios-sdk/issues/215